# Unicity of the equidistant set from the boundary of an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $V$ be a bounded open set such that if $x\in \partial V$ is a boundary point of $V$ then dist$(x,F)=a$ ($a>0$ constant). We also define a set $A$ to be the set of points $x$ such that dist$(x, V)<a$. We know that in general $\partial A$ and $F$ can be disjoint (see below), but what if we impose that $F$ be in the complement of $V$ ($A$ is an open set that contains $V$ and $\partial A$ is in the complement of $V$)? Can we say that $\partial A\subset F$?

As an example, suppose $n=1$, $F=[-1,1]$, $V=(-2,2)$ and $A=(-3,3)$. Here $\partial A$ and $F$ are disjoint, but if we move $F$ to the complement of $V$ (for example by setting $F=[-4,-3]\cup [3,4]$), then $\partial A=\partial F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I believe is no. Let $V=(0,1)\times(0,1)$, let $F$ be the
square with corners $(-1,-1),\ (2,-1),\ (2,2)$, and $(-1,2)$. The
minimum distance between $\partial V$ and $F$ is $a=1$. However,
$\partial A$ contains the circular arcs centered at
$(0,0),\ (1,0),\ (1,1)$, and $(0,1)$ which connect $(-1,0)$ to
$(0,-1)$, $(-1,1)$ to $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$ to $(1,2)$, and $(0,2)$ to
$(-1,-1)$. Thus, $\partial A\not\subset F$.